# x64 operation 'add imm8 to r/m8'

Tags: 64-bit, machine-code

The m8 version of this instruction takes an 8 bit value and adds it to an address in memory. Is the address AND the value of the address location 8 bits?  Or is the address some other size?

Comment: In x64, the effective address is self-evidently 64 bits, but points to a location 8 bits wide (m8). r/m8 refers to the size of the (register or memory) object pointed to, not the size of the address itself. As the Intel Software Developer Manual, Volume 2 says in _3.1.1.3_ , _r/m8 — A byte operand that is either the contents of a **byte general-purpose register** (AL, CL, DL, BL, AH, CH, DH, BH, BPL, SPL, DIL and SIL) or a **byte from memory**. Byte registers R8L - R15L are available using REX.R in 64-bit mode._ Emphasis mine.